# Unable to get the form value of html page to typescript page angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have my Typescript & HTML code looks like below:

```js
 stateCtrl = new FormControl();

  onSubmit(data) {

    this.onNameSelect(name);
    const deatails = JSON.stringify({
 
                                     CampaignId: data.Campaign
   
                                    });
    this.webService.CallDetails(deatails)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.Model = response;
      },
      (error) => console.error(error)
    );
  }
```

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(callform.value)" #callform="ngForm">

 <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">

  <mat-form-field>
  
    <input matInput placeholder="Campaign" aria-label="State" name="Campaign" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    
      <mat-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state.Name">
        <span>{{state.Name}}</span>
        
      </mat-option>
      
    </mat-autocomplete>
    
  </mat-form-field>
  
 </div>

</form>
```

now the problem is when I submit the form, I'm not getting the value of the input field. Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Here is my console log.

[image: This is my console log.]

Comment: if the solution below has solved your issue please mark it as Accepted so the tread gets to finished state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ngForm` directive, you don't need `formControl`, because they are used for reactive forms. I guess, you want to use a template driven form. You don't get value, because you need binding. From official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#the-ngform-directive):

> The NgForm directive supplements the form element with additional features. It holds the controls you created for the elements with an ngModel directive and name attribute, and monitors their properties, including their validity.

HTML template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Campaign" matInput placeholder="Campaign" aria-label="State" name="Campaign" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

Getting value in component from input:

```
onSubmit(data) {
  console.log('details', data.Campaign);
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/unable-to-get-the-form-value-of-html-page-to-typescript-page-an)

Comment: Hi, If I use [(ngModel)] I'm able to get the value of the field. But it is hampering the filter logic that I've implemented.

Answer (score 2):

So according to what I have read and understood in your code you need to implement `Reactive` form and for this, you need a `[formGroup]` in your form level first.
in your html:

```html
<form  [formGroup]="myFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(callform.value)" #callform="ngForm">
 <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Campaign" aria-label="State" name="Campaign" formControlName="stateCtrl">
  </mat-form-field>
 </div>

</form>
<button (click)="callform.onSubmit()"> Send
</button>
```

and in your `.ts` file:

```html
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-example.html',
})
export class FormFieldExample {
  myFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.myFormGroup = fb.group({
      stateCtrl: '',
    });
  }
    onSubmit(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Prudhvi Bharadwaj : if this solution has solved your issue please mark it as Accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngModel. This will definitely work.
How? See bellow:

HTML:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #callform="ngForm">

 <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">

  <mat-form-field>

    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="Campaign" placeholder="Campaign" aria-label="State" name="Campaign"  [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
    ...
```

TS:

```
Campaign: string 
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.Campaign);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that. But it didn't work. I've attached a log of my console on top. Please look.

Comment: Please guide me where. I can't find the log file.

Comment: Can you check now?

Comment: You aren't trying what i said.

Comment: @VirajKhatri this way of accessing (`console.log(Campaign);`) the property of component (service) is wrong

Comment: @Vadi were you addressing 'this' keyword?

Comment: @VirajKhatri yes

Comment: @Vadi changed it.

Answer (score -1):

You must add `formControlName="stateCtrl"` instead of `[formControl]="stateCtrl"`.
Good luck!